# Create and fill new table with existing data in R

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

Using R, how do I take several tables of results each with differing results columns and combine them row wise such that all results are captured, with NAs or blanks if a set of results doesn't have this column. Essentially I need to take data I have

[image: Data I have]

and turn it into data I want

[image: Data I want]

Note that I don't care about Brand Model and Year, they can just be stacked on top of each other.

Apologies for the poorly formatted post, I'm still finding my feet around here.

Answer (score 5):

We can use `rbindlist` from `data.table` after keeping it in a `list`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(df1, df2, df3), use.names = TRUE, fill=TRUE)
```

or use `bind_rows` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df1, df2, df3)
```

#### Update

In case, the data is in a single file as showed in the image, read it with `readLines`, then `split` it to a `list` and use `rbindlist`

```
lines1 <- trimws(readLines("temp1.csv"))
i1 <- cumsum(grepl("^Brand", lines1))
i2 <- lines1!=''
lst <- lapply(split(lines1[i2], i1[i2]), 
       function(x) read.csv(text=x, sep=""))
rbindlist(lst, use.names=TRUE, fill = TRUE)
```

Or

```
bind_rows(lst)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Brand = 1, Model ="A", Year = 2010:2014, 
              Dogs = c(0.71, 0.76, 0.40, 0.39, 0.67),
              Cats = c(0.64,0.06,0.18, 0.20, 0.23),
        Rabbits = c(0.56, 0.96, 0.90, 0.38, 0.73),
               stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df2 <- data.frame(Brand = 1, Model ="B", Year = c(2010, 2011, 2013, 2014), 
              Dogs = c(0.12, 0.43, 0.79, 0.29),
              Ducks = c(0.67, 0.48, 0.80, 0.70),
               stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df3 <-  data.frame(Brand = 1, Model ="C", Year = 2013:2014, 
              Dogs = c(0.76, 0.98),
              Cats = c(0.90, 0.84),
        Lions = c(0.12, 0.22),
              Wolves = c(0.75, 0.61),
               stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Wow, I actually feel a bit stupid it was one line of code once I had the dataframes. Where can I learn more about `dplyr`? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Using `merge()`:

```
> Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), list(df1, df2, df3))
   Brand Model Year Dogs Cats Rabbits Ducks Lions Wolves
1      1     A 2010 0.71 0.64    0.56    NA    NA     NA
2      1     A 2011 0.76 0.06    0.96    NA    NA     NA
3      1     A 2012 0.40 0.18    0.90    NA    NA     NA
4      1     A 2013 0.39 0.20    0.38    NA    NA     NA
5      1     A 2014 0.67 0.23    0.73    NA    NA     NA
6      1     B 2010 0.12   NA      NA  0.67    NA     NA
7      1     B 2011 0.43   NA      NA  0.48    NA     NA
8      1     B 2013 0.79   NA      NA  0.80    NA     NA
9      1     B 2014 0.29   NA      NA  0.70    NA     NA
10     1     C 2013 0.76 0.90      NA    NA  0.12   0.75
11     1     C 2014 0.98 0.84      NA    NA  0.22   0.61
```